# Private members of objects in an array not-modifiable

Tags: c++, pointers

I know there's a lot of literature on this, but I still can't figure it out. Let me start with a general description of the problem, and I'll post an MCVE.

**Description**: Basically I have an array of objects - I can get the values of their private members, but not set them. I think it's something to do with how I'm writing the setter methods, but I'm not sure how to modify it to make it right.

**main.cpp**

```
Store walmart;
Vip vip;

//  set vip points to 100
vip.setPoints(100);
walmart.setVip(vip, 0);
cout << "Points (before): " << walmart.getVip(0).getPoints() << endl;

//  set vip points to 200
walmart.getVip(0).setPoints(200);
cout << "Points (after): " << walmart.getVip(0).getPoints() << endl;
```

**Console output**

```
Points (before): 100
Points (after): 100  // <-- hoping this will be 200!
```

**Store.cpp**

```
void Store::setVip(Vip vip, int index) {
    this->vip[index] = vip;
}
Vip Store::getVip(int index) {
    return this->vip[index];
}
```

**Vip.cpp**

```
void Vip::setPoints(double points) {
    this->points = points;
}
double Vip::getPoints() {
    return this->points;
}
```

After Googling this problem, I'm convinced the problem is something to do with how I return the VIP object in the Store.cpp file with the `getVip(int index)` getter method - but I haven't yet succeeded in returning a modifiable reference.

Comment: Your function Vip::setPoints accepts the parameter points which is called exactly like one of your member variable which is accessible since you are in the class scope. That may be the problem actually. Try avoiding to use same names for ember variables and function parameters.

Comment: @RDGuida But they're using `this->` to disambiguate so that's not the problem.

Comment: your `getVip` should be `Vip& ` and not `Vip` because when you return a `Vip` a copy of the object wold be made and returned.. I am assuming your `this->vip` is an array of objects and not pointers

Comment: @gabhijit That's exactly right! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the signature of your 'getVip' method:

```
Vip Store::getVip(int index) { ... }
^^^
```

You are returning the 'Vip' object by value, which means you are returning a COPY of the object. Calling any method on that copy will result in a modification of that copy, not of the actual object in the array. What you want to do instead (as you have already mentioned) is to return a REFERENCE to the object, like so:

```
Vip& Store::getVip(int index) { return vip[index]; }
   ^ 
   "reference to a Vip object"
```

This way, you will be able to modify the object within the array. If you don't want to modify the object, it is often still viable to return a reference, just to prevent unnecessary copies, in this case you would return a const reference:

```
const Vip& Store::getVip(int index) const { return vip[index]; }
^^^^^    ^ 
"constant reference to a vip object"
```

Note that in all three cases, the body of the method does the exact same thing, only the return type of the method defines whether a copy is created or not.

Comment: Very detailed explanation - I'm still a bit hazy on pointers and references - I'll have to go back and have a look over these sections. Thanks for a great answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

The function `getVip` returns the `Vip` object *by value*, in other words a copy is made and returned. Modifying the copy will of course not modify the original. Instead return by reference.